# Lenovo Legion OS Selection - Dual Windows Startup screen is not appearing

Tags: multi-boot, lenovo-laptop, windows-11-preview

I have Windows 10 installed in my system, it was working fine. As Windows 11 is released, I thought to give it a try. I created a separate partition for test purpose, then installed Windows 11 on my Lenovo Legion 81Y6. But system is only loading newly installed Windows 11. System is not landing on OS selection screen.
How to enable Windows Startup selection Screen on my Lenovo Legion 81Y6?

Comment: Modify the BCD and add the entry so Windows can be booted.  However, you can easily screw up your machine.  So do the proper research.  Difficult to help without certain information about partitions, that hasn’t been provided